# Laravel: Controller method receives empty argument when called

Tags: php, laravel

during website development I've encountered this problem. I'm trying to call controller method from form inside a view. This is the code in a view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' =>['deletes', $client])) }}
    {{ Form::button('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'type'=>'submit']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

As you may see, I'm trying to pass object `$client` to method, that the route is referring to. The route is defined as this:

```
Route::post('/client_show/destroy','ClientsController@destroy')->name('deletes');
```

And this is the ClientController method:

```
public function destroy(Client $client) {
    $client->delete();
    return redirect('/client_show')->with('success', 'Deleted');
}
```

The problem is, even though the `$client` object is surely initialized in form, as soon as the `destroy(Client $client)` is invoked, the `$client` variable is empty there. So the deleting process fails and nothing is deleted. I've tried using

```
'url' =>['/client_show/destroy', $client]
```

instead, but nothing seems to work, everytime I get empty object. Thanks for any help.

Comment: and your form most likely sends a GET not POST

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai, tried it with explicit `'method'=>'POST'` but it didnt't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined any route parameters in your route definition. Because of this, when the `destroy()` controller method is called, it will be passed a plain `new Client` object.

Add the route parameter to your route, and you should be good:

```
Route::post('/client_show/destroy/{client}', 'ClientsController@destroy')->name('deletes');
```

You can take a look at [route model binding documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `{client}` to the route:

```
Route::post('/client_show/destroy/{client}','ClientsController@destroy')->name('deletes');
```

Then you need to pass the ID and not a whole object:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['deletes', $client->id]]) }}
```

Comment: Since Eloquent models implement the `UrlRoutable` interface, you can pass the whole object, and it will automatically pull the id out and use that in the url.

Comment: @patricus didn't know that. Thanks.